# How to allow only incoming response to a request made from the machine

Tags: linux, iptables

I am setting IP table rules in such a way that input traffic from only certain IP range is allowed.

```bsh
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m iprange --src-range x.y.0.0-x.y.255.255 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth0 -m iprange --src-range 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 -j DROP
```

And after this rule the access to my machine is blocked for ip's which are not in the range I allowed. Which is fine.

But now I want an exception to this rule, If from my machine I want to access some http web link, then I want it to be proceeded. But not other way around that is if the blocked IP tries to access the http web link hosted on my machine then that should not be allowed.

I tried adding below rule along with previously mentioned rules

```bsh
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But this does not work, if I add NEW in the above state list then my machine can access the web link from blocked ip but that works in both ways and the blocked ip also can access my weblink, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

> iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Did you add this *after*

> -A INPUT -i eth0 -m iprange --src-range 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 -j DROP

?

If so the rule is never going to fire. Make sure that RELATED,ESTABLISHED rules are at the top of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding common firewall concepts here. You are using stateless incoming firewall rules to block and unblock outgoing connections. It is not impossible but it is illogical. Using CIDR networks would be simpler than ranges and also outbound filter table should be used.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s x.y.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d a.b.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

With these rules :

- x.y.0.0/16 network block, should access to your machine.
- Your machine should access to a.b.0.0/16 network block.
- Every other access, outbound and inbound, should be impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May be I did not explain it correctly. I have to restrict access to  my machine to few IP's only. Now I came across a scenario where my machine need to access some random web links. And as I have no restrictions on the outgoing traffic, the request is made but the response is blocked as the weblink server is not in the allowed IP range. I am not sure if by any way I can achieve to accept packets which belongs to the response for the request made from my machine.